# Can I have other Followers if I am married?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So I married Cosnatch, the drunk brawler from Markarth, and am quite happy with my choice. He is hilarious and good to have around in battle.  However, as I continue with quests and faction storylines, I am noticing that occasionally the reward is that you can take on another follower from time to time. (Ex. Cicero in the Dark Brotherhood) I do not wish to off my husband, but when I ask him to "wait" in our home, then try to employ another follower, they all just say "You already have someone in your party."

Am I to believe that once you take your beloved on an adventure with you, you have to miss the perks of several quests? (There is also a Daedric Quest where you must lead a Follower to death, which would be null and void unless I wanted poor Cosnatch dead.) Or am I missing an obvious step? If I tell him we should "part ways", will he remain in our home? Will I be able to eventually travel with him again? This part of the game is not very clear.

Answer (score 13):

You don't have to make him wait, you need to select the option "It's time for us to part ways" (or something similar).

Don't worry, he'll be at your home, this doesn't mean a divorce. Marriage and followers are two different things